# Hide nodes outside stackpane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, show-hide, scenebuilder

I want to hide nodes outside of stackpane as such a way that it do not takes space , also do not shows....
For example. I am in scene builder. I have anchor pane as a root. In achor pane i have stack pane in middle of it. In Stack pane i have a button and i move it half out side of stack pane using translate ..
I want to hide area outside of stackpane also it do not take any space...
Please help me if any one know or give me suggestions in alternative way

I have tried in javafx codding also in scene buider but do not find any solutions. also i do not find any help on the internet on this topic . thanks..

Comment: My main problem is when i use group in javafx scene builder. it  takes spaces that is out side of some container i.e. a button in anchor pane out side some area (half) i want tha the area which i outside of anchor pane deleted or hide in such a way this it takes no space...

Comment: By definition anything outside of some layout does not take space (as layout is concerned). Otherwise the layout bounds would be larger. The result of transformations are only that the render position of a node is adjusted (with the exception of children of `Group`); the parent layout treats the child as untransformed for determining it's bounds/the space it uses. As for the other issue: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty (IIrc SceneBuilder doesn't support this property though.)